# Do DeviceOrientationControls still work with three.js r104?

Tags: three.js, webvr

I create webvr on mobile by three.js and I use DeviceOrientationControls but it's doesn't work, DeviceOrientationControls have lastest modified year ago, I don't know it's still can work with latest version three.js? can tell me it's still working or not?

demo:https://demoviss.herokuapp.com/

code:

```
sceneSetup = () => {
   this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
   this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
     80,
     window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
     0.1,
     1000
   );
   this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
   this.raycaster.setFromCamera({ x: 0, y: 0 }, this.camera);
   this.camera.position.y = 1.6;
   this.camera.position.x = 0;
   this.camera.position.z = -0.001;
   this.controls = new DeviceOrientationControls(this.camera);
   this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
   this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
   this.renderer.vr.enabled = true;

   this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
   document.body.appendChild(WEBVR.createButton(this.renderer));

   this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
   });
 };
```

Comment: The official example for `THREE.DeviceOrientationControls` does work on my Pixel (1) with latest Chrome: https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation. It also uses the latest version of `three.js` (`R104`).

Comment: It works for me Iphone5s too and how can I integrate with reactJS?

Comment: this.controls = new DeviceOrientationControls(this.camera);
have error THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.

Comment: Can you please remove the usage of `WebVR` first? I see in Chrome the error: `navigator.xr.requestDevice is not a function`.

Comment: Already removed, please check again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging your application, it seems the following line in `addCustomSceneObjects()` causes the runtime error:

```
this.scene.add(this.controls);
```

`THREE.DeviceOrientationControls` is not derived from `Object3D` so adding an instance to the scene graph is invalid. After creating the controls, you just have to call `THREE.DeviceOrientationControls.update()` in your animation loop similar to the [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation). This is something you have to add to your `animate()` function.

`three.js R104`